# Can I multiply a personalization string variable?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, string, merge-field

Is there a way that I can pull a personalization string variable, such as someone's last purchase amount, and multiply it? For example:

I pull **%%Last Purchase Amount%%**, which is **100**, and I want to multiply it by **1.5** so that the string resolves to **150**. Is there a way I can do this through AMPscript or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing.

You could do something like this:

```
%%[

var @lastPurchaseAmount
set @lastPurchaseAmount= AttributeValue("Last Purchase Amount")

if empty(@lastPurchaseAmount) then
  set @lastPurchaseAmount = "0"
else 
  set @lastPurchaseAmount = multiply(@lastPurchaseAmount,1.5) 
endif

]%%
<br>Last Purchase Amount: %%=v(@lastPurchaseAmount)=%%
```

You can also format the output using the [**FormatNumber()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/FormatNumber), [**FormatCurrency()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/FormatCurrency) or [**Format()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/Format) functions.

**Reference**

- [**AttributeValue() function**](https://ampscript.guide/book/AttributeValue)
- [**Multiply() function**](https://ampscript.guide/book/Multiply)